# Something with Tooltips using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript

well this is for the people that know about Jquery more about me and this is my question:

I'm using bootstrap framework to create my web
I've added some tooltips to try these
But i've noticed that the code that i'm using doesn't work for 2 or more tooltips

I mean, this is the code of the JS:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#tooltips').tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

And this is the code to call the tooltip:

```
<a href='#' id='tooltips' data-placement='top' title='this is a tooltip'>
```

I was sure if i place that code i'll able to use it for 2 or more tooltips, but i can't.

To resume: I want to know why i can't use it for 2 or more tooltips instead of one, cause i don't want to had like 10 lines of JS for 4 tooltips

Answer (score 2):

You can't have the same `id` value more than once in a page. Use `class` instead. It's a very common mistake.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.tooltips').tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

```
<a href='#' class='tooltips' data-placement='top' title='tooltip'>...</a>
<a href='#' class='tooltips' data-placement='top' title='another tooltip'>...</a>
<a href='#' class='tooltips' data-placement='top' title='another tooltip'>...</a>
```

You should use the [HTML Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) to check your page before trying to debug javascript or css. Make sure it passes 100% before trying to solve any problems.

Comment: Adding `data-toggle="tooltip"` doesn't automatically add the tooltip functionality. You have to initialize on specific elements with `.tooltip()`

Comment: Yeah, I've gotten caught with that too before. I would expect all bootstrap features to be automatically detected by attributes optionally, but something that is triggered naturally by a hover happens too often to be automatically detected efficiently. Unlike modals, which are opened on click

Comment: @WesleyMurch Thank you so much bro, That's what i've been looking for, well as you said it's a common error for a new user of jquery like me :p

And again, Thanks alot